# Multi languages in ABP framework

Tags: angular, abp

I'm doing a project using ABP framework, but I'm having problems with how to do multi-language without any direction. Please tell me how to do select multi languages ​​function using json translate files on my Angular frontend without getting the default translation of the app framework.?

```
import { AccountConfigModule } from '@abp/ng.account/config';
import { CoreModule } from '@abp/ng.core';
import { ThemeBasicModule } from '@abp/ng.theme.basic';
import { ErrorHandler, ThemeSharedModule } from '@abp/ng.theme.shared';
import { ApplicationRef, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { APP_ROUTE_PROVIDER } from './route.provider';
import { AbpOAuthModule } from '@abp/ng.oauth';
import { AdministrationConfigModule } from './administration/config/administration-config.module';
import { NgSelectComponent, NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import { SettingManagementConfigModule } from '@abp/ng.setting-management/config';
import { FeaturesConfigModule } from './features/config/features-config.module';
import { MdbTooltipModule } from 'mdb-angular-ui-kit/tooltip';
import { VALIDATION_BLUEPRINTS } from '@ngx-validate/core';
import { DEFAULT_VALIDATION_BLUEPRINTS } from '@abp/ng.theme.shared';
import { en } from './shared/locales/en-US';
import { vi} from './shared/locales/vi-VN';
import { OAuthStorage } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormRequestInterceptor } from './shared/interceptors/form-request.interceptor';
import { AuthInterceptor } from './shared/interceptors/auth.interceptor';
import { CurrencyMaskModule } from 'ng2-currency-mask';
import { CacheInterceptor } from './shared/interceptors/cache.interceptor';
import { CacheResolverService } from './shared/services/cache-resolver.service';
import { CustomErrorHandler } from './shared/handlers/error.handler';
import { registerLocale } from './core/i18n/register-locale';
import { storeLocaleData } from '@abp/ng.core/locale';

export class CustomCookieStorage implements OAuthStorage {
  getItem(key: string): string {
    const name = key + "=";
    const decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    const cookieArray = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for (let i = 0; i < cookieArray.length; i++) {
      let cookie = cookieArray[i];
      while (cookie.charAt(0) === ' ') {
        cookie = cookie.substring(1);
      }
      if (cookie.indexOf(name) === 0) {
        return cookie.substring(name.length, cookie.length);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  removeItem(key: string): void {
    document.cookie = key + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
  }

  setItem(key: string, data: string): void {
    document.cookie = key + '=' + data + '; path=/; SameSite=Lax;';
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CoreModule.forRoot({
      environment,
      registerLocaleFn: registerLocale,
      localizations: [en,vi]
    }),
    AbpOAuthModule.forRoot(),
    ThemeSharedModule.forRoot(),
    AccountConfigModule.forRoot(),
    FeaturesConfigModule.forRoot(),
    AdministrationConfigModule.forRoot(),
    ThemeBasicModule.forRoot(),
    SettingManagementConfigModule.forRoot(),
    NgSelectModule,
    MdbTooltipModule,
    CurrencyMaskModule
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  exports: [NgSelectModule, NgSelectComponent],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: FormRequestInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    // {
    //   provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    //   useClass: AuthInterceptor,
    //   multi: true
    // },
    // {
    //   provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    //   useClass: CacheInterceptor,
    //   multi: true,
    // },
    // {
    //   provide: CacheResolverService,
    //   useClass: CacheResolverService,
    // },
    {
      provide: VALIDATION_BLUEPRINTS,
      useValue: {
        ...DEFAULT_VALIDATION_BLUEPRINTS,
        invalidName: "::invalidName[{{value}}]",
        invalidPhone: "::invalidPhone[{{value}}]",
        invalidBlank: "{{message}}",
        invalidProductName: "{{message}}",
        invalidAccountName: "{{message}}",
        uniqueUsername: "{{message}}",
        uniqueEmail: "{{message}}",
        uniqueRoleName: "{{message}}",
        invalidEmailPattern: "{{message}}",
        uniqueTenantName: "{{message}}",
        uniqueTenantEmail: "{{message}}"
      },
    },
    APP_ROUTE_PROVIDER,
    {
      provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: CustomErrorHandler
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

in my register-locale file

```
export function registerLocale(locale: string) {
  return import(
    /* webpackChunkName: "_locale-[request]"*/
    /* webpackInclude: /[/\\](en|fr).js/ */
    /* webpackExclude: /[/\\]global|extra/ */
    `@angular/common/locales/${ 'en' || locale}`
  );
}
```

I have two folder translate like this.
[[image]]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgUjY.png)

and inside of it
[image]

I want to use my translate file.Vietnamese translate doesn't have in default of abp translate file But it's can't. Everyone help me please.

Answer (score 0):

The translation source is a backend app. ABP provides localization keys via the Rest API. The app sends a request to
`/api/abp/application-localization?cultureName=en&onlyDynamics=false` url. Response constain all translations

So I couldn't understand your main goal. Could you describe why you want to change localization resource?

if you want to override some keys. you can use instant keyword. please check the docs
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/Angular/Localization